# Call different method if first one fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails/Ruby. I have the following:

```
  def normalize
    rg = ReverseGeocoder.new(lat, lng, LOCALITY).process!
    return save_normalized_values(rg) if rg[:results].any?

    rg = ReverseGeocoder.new(lat, lng, ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1).process!
    return save_normalized_values(rg) if rg[:results].any?
  end
```

While this works, is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 1):

If you could make `.process!` return false on a failure you could do this

```
rg = ReverseGeocoder.new(lat, lng, LOCALITY).process! || ReverseGeocoder.new(lat, lng, ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1).process!
save_normalized_values(rg) if rg[:results].any?
```

Otherwise I don't see a cleaner way, just different:

```
rg = ReverseGeocoder.new(lat, lng, LOCALITY).process!
rg[:results] || rg = ReverseGeocoder.new(lat, lng, ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1).process!
rg[:results] && save_normalized_values(rg)
```